# Do google map GroundOverlays have anti-aliasing on by default?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I could not find any documentation regarding this. I have observed that my images are anti-aliased by default when loaded on a google map `GroundOverlay` in Android. Do google map GroundOverlays have anti-aliasing on by default?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anti-aliasing is used in Ground Overlays, and it's not configurable. See antialias for `android.graphics.Bitmap` in [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: do you have a source where you found this?

Comment: Hello, the link you pointed out is source code of Bitmap class I am not sure how it is related to my question directly.

Comment: It's related because that's what is being used, and it has antialias set to true.

Comment: bitmaps have option to setAntiAlias(false) as well. What if I pass a bitmap to `GroundOverlay` with AntiAlias set to false?

Comment: I mean you can try that if you want...? Like I said, it's not configurable. It won't work.